# Capacitive circuit

Tags: capacitance

I was studying in one of my books that in a capacitive circuit in steady state with battery remaining connected ,if any external agent goes on separating the plates of the capacitor very slowly then the potential of capacitor decreases . But I have my doubt that when the external agent does work against the electrostatic force then the energy stored in the agent will be transferred to the electrostatic field energy as the K.E. of the plates are remaining zero.That's why initially the potential of the capacitor must increase

Comment: "battery" usually is synonymous with "constant voltage source." If the capacitor is connected in parallel with a constant voltage source, then you may assume that the source will either supply or absorb whatever amount of energy is necessary to _force_ the voltage between the plates to remain constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume the plate separation is much smaller than the dimensions of the plates themselves, then the field between the plates does not depend on their separation: 
$$E=\frac \sigma{\epsilon_0}$$ 
Therefore the potential difference between the plates is:
$$V=\int_0^d E\ dl=Ed=\frac{\sigma d}{\epsilon_0}$$

But, if we have the plates hooked up to a battery, the potential difference must remain constant. Therefore, if $d$ increases, we must have $\sigma$, the charge density on each plate, decreasing to keep the potential difference constant.

Your analysis is correct if we charge the capacitor and then disconnect the battery. Then as $d$ increases, $V$ also increases.

Comment: The external agent is doing work to separate the plates.Then in which form of energy does the energy of the external agent getting converted into?

Comment: @RifatSafin Which case are you referring to?

Comment: When it remains connected to the battery

Comment: @RifatSafin You are doing work on the charges plates, but the battery is also doing negative work on the charges as the charge density decreases. So no net work is being done, which is why the potential remains constant.

Comment: @RifatSafin If you think the answer is good enough you can give it an upvote. If it sufficiently answers your question please mark it as the correct answer,